# SQL Server to PostgreSQL migration - script conversion error

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I'm in the process of migrating a SQL Server database to PostgreSQL, thus started to evaluate `sqlserver2pgsql` for the purpose.

When I ran the below to convert the schema targeting PostgreSQL in command prompt

```
sqlserver2pgsql.pl -f test\DCMM.sql -b test\DCMM-before.sql -a test\DCMM-after.sql -u test\DCMM-unsure.sql
```

I got the below error

> **Line <create table [dbo].[dc_mass_mailer] (
> (1) not understood. This is a bug at sqlserver2pgsql.pl line 2551, <$file> line 1.**

I'm using PERL version 5.32.1 of Strawberry for 64-bit and I'm using Windows 11.

Had anyone came across this kind of error?

Comment: Looks like a support question for the writers of the tool?

Comment: This question is redundant, an issue was logged for [sqlserver2pgsql](https://github.com/dalibo/sqlserver2pgsql/issues/172) a few hours ago.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning fellow team mate did it.